# Remove DB2 FODC files from server

Tags: db2

I have a SAP system which has DB2 and the DB2 creates FODC files and stores the same in server under /db2dump folder. I have FODC files from past two years and its filling up my server disk space. Whether removing these files will cause any issue? Do I need to backup these files before removing them?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a programming question, so you're in the wrong place.

Comment: You can remove these old directories and files. However, if they continue to be created, you should try to resolve the cause so that they don't continue to reappear.

Comment: hi, no FODC are crashdump. you can delete them, but i advise you to contact the support to find the root cause of theses FODC